# How i'm I suppose to use <DIV> while creating a border to the right

Tags: html, css, htmlelements

I'm learning HTML online through my community college and is hard.

"In this assignment you will create an HTML document that includes the div element to showcase your favorite movie.  You will include the movie title, the year the movie was released, the main star or stars and their character(s) name.  The div element will render on the right side of the page.  See below for an example of what your .html should look like.

[image]

this is my code so far. I need some guidance on who to accomplish shifting the text with the border to the right without CSS

```html
<div align="right" style="border: 1px solid black" hj>
  <h1><span>Inception</span></h1>
  <h2><span> Release year: 2010 </span></h2>
  <h3><span> Leonardo DiCaprio as Dom Cobb </span></h3>
</div>

<h2> My Three Favorite musical acts are: </h2>

<ul>
  <li>Korn</li>
  <li>Bring Me the Horizon </li>
  <li> Linkin Park </li>
</ul>

<h2> My Three Favorite Foods are: </h2>

<ol type="i">
  <li>Pizza</li>
  <li>Ceviche</li>
  <li>Burger</li>
</ol>

<h2> My dream Vacation is: </h2>
<p> Europe </p>
<dl> My dream vacation would be to visit europe and it's major cities. Paria, London, Berlin just to name a few. </dl>
```

Comment: Without CSS? Are you sure that is a requirement? I don't know you could create that border without CSS.

Comment: I posted it the code. sorry.

Comment: You can't do it without CSS, it's a ridiculous requirement. You need to use CSS for borders

Comment: yes, it should be the inset border from what I've been able to figure out. How would I insert CSS into this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work like this.
I also improved your `<dl>` element, which was not correctly written, by adding the `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags inside.

Cheers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;float:right;width:300px;padding:10px;">
        <h1><span>Inception</span></h1>
        <h2><span> Release year: 2010 </span></h2>
        <h3><span> Leonardo DiCaprio as Dom Cobb </span></h3>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-left: 10px;">
        <h2> My Three Favorite musical acts are: </h2>

        <ul>
            <li>Korn</li>
            <li>Bring Me the Horizon </li>
            <li> Linkin Park </li>
        </ul>

        <h2> My Three Favorite Foods are: </h2>

        <ol type="i">
            <li>Pizza</li>
            <li>Ceviche</li>
            <li>Burger</li>
        </ol>
        <h2> My dream Vacation is: </h2>
        <dl>
            <dt>Europe</dt>
            <dd>My dream vacation would be to visit europe and it's major cities. Paria, London, Berlin just to name a few.</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
<div align="right" style="border: 1px solid black;float:right;width:300px" hj>
  <h1><span>Inception</span></h1>
  <h2><span> Release year: 2010 </span></h2>
  <h3><span> Leonardo DiCaprio as Dom Cobb </span></h3>
</div>

<div style=" float:left;">
    <h2> My Three Favorite musical acts are: </h2>

    <ul>
      <li>Korn</li>
      <li>Bring Me the Horizon </li>
      <li> Linkin Park </li>
    </ul>

    <h2> My Three Favorite Foods are: </h2>

    <ol type="i">
      <li>Pizza</li>
      <li>Ceviche</li>
      <li>Burger</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<h2> My dream Vacation is: </h2>
<p> Europe </p>
<dl> My dream vacation would be to visit europe and it's major cities. Paria, London, 
 Berlin just to name a few. </dl>
```